# Azure Storage and incremental backup

Tags: azure-storage

I have a account in AZURE STORAGE and i'm using Azure Storage Explorer to send files to my account.

The problem is i need some software to make incremental backup from my local machine to azure storage account. Because all day have new files and i can't copy everything again.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy) via option /XO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq#how-azure-backup-works)  and install [MARS agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault) to store daily incremental backups to an azure storage account.